# How to add new field with out replace the old document?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm trying to implement many-to-many relationship between user and group in my java mobile application, So on a user can be in multiple groups and a group can have multiple users, I'm using firebase to store my data.

i have found this example :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH5VB.png)

and this is my code :

[image]

The problem here is that push generates a new id then it adds the Id of the group with the value true inside :

[image]

but I don't want that if I delete.push() I only found one field of the last group i have added so i think that every time i added a new group it take the place of the last one

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your data structure, nor what you want the output to be. What is the meaning of the `-M...` keys under `younssbouch`? I get they come from calling `push()`, but what are they for? Why don't you just call `...child("user_enrollments").child(username).setValue(true)` to indicate that `username` was enrolled?

Comment: in this user_enrollments collection i want to store all groups id that user younesbouch intergrate in so **Id** in  ` ...child("User_enrolments").child(username).child(**Id**).setValue("true");` is referenced to the group id in group Collection

Comment: In that case I don't understand what you want the code to do. Please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to: 1) show the code as text, and not as a screenshot, 2) Show the JSON that you want to get after running the code with an existing username (I also recommend posting this as text, but make sure it's valid JSON in that case).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be overcomplicating things in your data structure. If you want to track the usernames of who has enrolled, how about simple doing:

```
User_enrollments
  .child("user_enrollments")
  .child(username)
  .setValue(true)
```